# Falling metal cylinders more devastating than a nuke?

Tags: forces, nuclear-physics, projectile

I just saw [*G.I JOE - Retaliation*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1583421/). In the movie the bad guys (spoiler alert)

> destroy London by dropping a large metal cylinder from space onto the city.

Could this device cause more destruction than a nuclear weapon? If so, how?

Comment: The real answer is "because MovieMagic" , but you could calculate the total kinetic energy of a body of given mass launched at a given velocity and then dropping down the gravity well.  We do this all the time with meteors :-)

Comment: If you are interested in the effects of kinetic energy weapons, perhaps you could bring this up in the science fiction forum. Ask about The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress by Robert Heinlein. Or one of the books by by Vernor Vinge. I think it is A Fire Upon the Deep.

Comment: "Anathem" (Stephenson) involves a certain amount of "rodding" too.

Answer (score 4):

Also known as *Rods From God*, the idea may be somewhat practical in the far future, although they are significantly weaker than nuclear arms. For example, with rods situated at an orbital radius of 500 miles (twice that of the International Space Station), the energy density becomes (in Mathematica):

```
<< PhysicalConstants`
Convert[GravitationalConstant EarthMass (1/EarthRadius - 1/(
    EarthRadius + 500 Mile)), Joule/Gram]
```

> (7003.49 Joule)/Gram

For comparison, the energy density of gasoline is 45,000 Joule/Gram, and most conventional nitrate explosives clock in at around 4,000 to 10,000 Joule/Gram.

At larger radii (10,000 miles) the energy becomes more significant, but still comparatively small:

```
Convert[GravitationalConstant EarthMass (1/EarthRadius - 1/(
    EarthRadius + 10000 Mile)), Joule/Gram]
```

> (44771.9 Joule)/Gram

Comment: Is this a vertical drop from an orbiting satellite? Isn't it impractical to negate the orbital speed from the rod?

Comment: @LDC3: Yeah, just a vertical drop, it ignores the preexisting orbital speed. However, you know that the orbital kinetic energy is bounded above by the depth the object resides within the Earth's potential well, which means that the orbital kinetic energy is bounded by $GM_\text{E}/R_\text{E}$, which is 62515.8 Joule/Gram, only slightly higher than gasoline energy density.

Comment: @LCD3: Of course, if they're not coming from an orbit, but instead are propelled towards Earth by rockets or something, then it can probably get much higher.