# Can a projectile bullet kill?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, projectile, speed, biology

Today, I was watching a movie, in which a person shot a gun in air. The bullet went high in sky, became stationary for a moment and dived back and killing a non-innocent person by hitting him in head directly. And yes, the bullet was shot at near vertical.

But, the question is, is it possible?

I know that an ideal projectile will reach ground with speed equal to launching speed. But in this case air is also present which will constantly decrease bullet's velocity, until it reaches it terminal velocity. But is it fatal?

Also there is another movie in which they make a type of bomb with gravity only. They use a long and heavy rod planted in a satellite (no explosives), which whenever required, is not launched, but just dropped. And they showed it powerful enough to clean a whole city. Is it actually possible and do we need to care? Can someone do this in reality? I know in ideally it should hit at $11 km s^{-1}$, but what about reality?

As per WillO's comment, I found this in a Wikipedia's comment on G.I. Joe on the page [kinetic bombardment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_bombardment):

> However, the movie misrepresented physics by claiming the rod would not be "launched" or "fired" but merely "dropped". If it were released without force it would orbit the Earth in the same manner as the platform itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about survivability of a person given certain scenarios and, separately, about whether movie physics is real or not.

Comment: Also, Q2 is a dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110108/25301

Comment: What does "just dropped" mean?  What causes the long heavy rod to leave its orbit?

Comment: @WillO These were the words used in movie, but actually, they seemed to push it a little to do so.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos The point is, is terminal velocity of a bullet large enough to kill someone? I think it is still a nice question and you may see as per John W. answer it is not for a vertical case, it loses its direction due to tumbling..

Comment: @PranshuKhandal whether someone can be killed by something it not is **not** a question of physics but of biology.

Comment: @Qmechanic Sir, will you please explain why is it off-topic? What can I do? It seems a nice question to me.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos main question is, it the speed enough? and not, will person die. that's about physics. i know person may or may not die, it always depends, and that's not my question

Comment: No, it really isn't.

Comment: Hi  PranshuKhandal. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Re, "a...heavy rod...in a satellite...which...[is] just dropped." The "just dropped" part of that story is completely unrealistic. You can't "just drop" something from orbit.  From the satellite's point of view, the rod would not go anywhere at all if the satellite simply let go of it.  In order to hit a target on the ground, you'd need to strap a rocket to the rod, and fire the rocket to change the rod's trajectory.  In a practical system, there would be no separation of anything from anything else.  The rod, plus its reaction thrusters and some electronics would _be_ the satellite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this would be better suited for the Skeptics SE, but here goes...

The Mythbusters tested the "bullet fired into the air" myth and concluded it's plausible under certain conditions (bullet fired under an angle so it maintains it's spin and thus doesn't tumble). See [here](https://mythresults.com/episode50).

As for the second thing, it's called [kinetic bombardment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_bombardment). The US Air Force is doing research on it and claims a tungsten rod 6m long and 0.3m in diameter would deliver the energy equivalent of several tons of TNT. So yes, absolutely possible. "Parking" such rods in an orbit around Earth would be quite expensive though.